# Preload TBB in .NET

Tags: .net, tbb

I have an application which has a C#.NET GUI. When the applications does some heavy computations, it loads native DLLs. Is it possible to preload the Intel TBB library somehow, so that the native code uses malloc et al from TBB?

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense. Isn't TBB "consumed" at compile-time?

Comment: You can preload TBB at startup and the program will automatically use memory functions from TBB without changing a single line of code. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506096 The question is how to do the linking/startup for .NET.